# Array change subscriptions returning undefined

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

Below is a small poc i was working on depicting various functionalities of knockout. I want to call the subscribe method for observableArray, but it returns undefined, i tried two different ways, i am unable to understand what is incorrect. any guidance welcome.
I was referring to this article. here [Array change subscriptions](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2013/10/08/knockout-3-0-release-candidate-available/)
You can also find the both my jsfiddles below.

```
    self.cartList = ko.observableArray();
    self.cartList.subcribe(
    function (newValue) {
        console.log(ko.toJS(self.cartList));
    }, null, "arrayChange");
```

[fiddle 1](http://jsfiddle.net/jqq8y067/3/)

[fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/jqq8y067/6/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple typo -- you spelled `subscribe` wrong.

```
self.cartList.subscribe(
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jqq8y067/7/

Comment: :( cant believe i did that.